# Consecutive vb.net get request hangs and times out

Tags: vb.net, post, request

I'm making a vb.net application that makes get requests every 35 seconds, the first and second requests occur normally and take less than 1 second but from the third request there is no return and it reaches the timeouts regardless of the set timeouts.

The sub that is called every 35 seconds is as follows:

```
Sub Eventos(ByVal token)
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse
        Dim responseString As String
        Dim jsonObject As JObject
        Dim EventosArray As JArray


        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Function() True
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12


        request = CType(WebRequest.Create("https://merchant-api.ifood.com.br/order/v1.0/events:polling"), HttpWebRequest)
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " & token)
        request.Method = "GET"
        request.ContentType = "application/json"
        request.Timeout = 60000

        response = CType(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        responseString = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd()

        If (responseString <> "") Then
            jsonObject = JObject.Parse("{events:" & responseString & "}")

            EventosArray = jsonObject("events")

            For Each evento As JObject In EventosArray
                If (evento("code") = "PLC") Then
                    Module1.orderId = evento("orderId")
                    Module1.ApagaEventos(evento.ToString.Replace(vbCr, "").Replace(vbLf, ""), token)

                Else
                    Module1.ApagaEventos(evento.ToString.Replace(vbCr, "").Replace(vbLf, ""), token)

                End If

            Next

            Console.WriteLine(jsonObject)

        End If


    End Sub
```

I've tested it with timeouts between 1 minute and 10 minutes with no changes. I've already checked the server request limit, however it is over 5 per minute so this shouldn't be a problem.

I tested it on different devices using Windows 7 and 10 and the behavior was identical on all.

I tested this request using Postman and I manage to get the answers in the right time and with several consecutive requests successfully.

I would like to know why this is happening and how to get around this problem.

Comment: If you use a tool like [Postman](https://www.postman.com/), are you able to get responses in the timeframe you are expecting?

Comment: Yes, using the Postman I can get the answers in the right time and with several successful successive requests. I will add this information in the question.

Comment: You're supposed to dispose of the HttpWebResponse and all the Streams you open. Declare them all with `Using` statements -- Not clear why you validate all server certificates here or why you're settings the `ServicePointManager` in this function call. If actually needed (only Windows 7 and 2008 R2), it should be done once, prior to the calls

Comment: I just tested this, it really works, thank you very much